# Automation of Unix server by SSH using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation

I access my Unix server via ssh and I always do the same commands. This is the list of commands (first I login to the server):

1. `cd /etc/openvpn`
2. `vi log.log`
3. `/huaze` (I'm using search function of vi)
4. If I found the string / word I then proceed to step 5-up to end, (if I didn't find the string, I just log out)
5. `:q` (exiting vi)
6. `service openvpn stop`
7. `service openvpn start`
8. Log off

As you can see, I want to harness the power of automation and I can accomplish this with a click of a button; unfortunately this is challenging since it's ASP.NET and C# is going to access a Unix ssh protocol. So, how can I accomplish this in the most straightforward way.

Comment: Why do you want to do this through ASP.NET? Why not do it from the Windows command line or from a Console program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems the [SSH .NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com) library should give you the tools you need to SSH into any host, execute commands, and read the results. It shouldn't matter whether the host is Linux.